# why does grep -v $b <<< $a output, but not grep -v $a <<< $b?

Tags: bash, variables, grep

I am trying to get two variables containing multiple lines of directories to each output the lines that don't match with eachother, I can get this for one variable but not the other

The contents of the variables

```
$ echo $a

./old.file.name

./old.file.name/old.file.name.mkv

./old.file.name/old.file.name.nfo

./old.file.name.sh

$ echo $b

./new file name

./new file name/new file name.mkv

./new file name/new file name.nfo

./old.file.name.sh
```

The grep that works like I expected and it's output

```
$ grep -v $b <<< $a

./old.file.name

./old.file.name/old.file.name.mkv

./old.file.name/old.file.name.nfo
```

The grep that doesn't output anything

```
$ grep -v $a <<< $b
```

I was expecting this from it

```
$ grep -v $a <<< $b

./new file name

./new file name/new file name.mkv

./new file name/new file name.nfo
```

Comment: Are you sure that `echo $a` and `echo $b` do what you say?

Comment: Without even thinking about anything else, start by quoting your variables. `grep -v "$b" ....`  Double quote everything.

Comment: I'm surprised all of your code attempts aren't generating a slew of error messages due to the unquoted variable references (eg, `$a` instead of `"$a"`)

Comment: Unless the OP's shell is actually zsh instead of bash and they tagged the question incorrectly; that would explain the missing errors.

Comment: Anyhow -- keep in mind that grep takes patterns to match, not exact strings, unless you pass it non-default options like `-F`. If you aren't giving us names that you've tested that the problem actually happens with, that's crucial missing information. A name with square brackets, for example, will canonically not match itself.

Comment: please update the question to include the assignment statements for the two variables; alternatively, update the question to include the output from these 2 commands: `base64 <<< "$a"` and `base64 <<< "$b"`; we can use these results to rebuild an exact copy of `a` and `b` in our environments

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce any of OP's outputs with the data provided and using OP's `grep` calls; at this point I'll focus on how to generate the expected output ...

---

It appears (to me) the intention is to display *lines* that exist in only one of the variables; in this case I'd opt for `comm` though it will be necessary to sort the data.

One `comm` idea, while also addressing the other issues (double quoting variables, sorting data):

```
# display lines that only exist in $b

$ comm -13 <(echo "$a"| sort) <(echo "$b"| sort)
./new file name
./new file name/new file name.mkv
./new file name/new file name.nfo

# display lines that only exist in $a:

$ comm -23 <(echo "$a"| sort) <(echo "$b"| sort)
./old.file.name
./old.file.name/old.file.name.mkv
./old.file.name/old.file.name.nfo
```

**NOTES:**

- this assumes 'identical' lines are truly identical, right down to the same number of leading/trailing spaces, non-printing characters, etc
- if there could be duplicate lines, and you don't want duplicates in the output, then you could replace all `sort` calls with `sort -u`